# Passing hidden field value along with textbox value through an array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I wrote this function to push values in text boxes which is inside a `<p>` tag to an array and it is working all good.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#form_timesheet").submit(function(e){
    var arr=[];
    var i=0;
    $("#addedRows p").find("input[type=text]").each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).val());
    i++;        
 });
 });
```

now i want to pass a hidden field value along with this text box values through the same array. how can i do that by editing the line '   $("#addedRows p").find("input[type=text]").each(function()'

Comment: just a guess but perhaps `input[type='text'],input[type='hidden']`

Comment: I think you need to find `input[type=hidden]` if you want to pass value to hidden field with jquery

Comment: Can you please create fiddle??

Comment: @SunilGehlot no need to create fiddle because he wants to find only the hidden element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standej is mostly right , just modify his answer as following:

```
$("#addedRows p").find("input[type=hidden], input[type=text]").each(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add

```
$("#addedRows p").find("input[type=hidden]").each(function(){
arr.push($(this).val()); // and add whatever value in it
```

Comment: i want type="text" as well as hidden

Comment: then set up in input field display=none

Comment: oh i think i missundestood you sorry :)